# Pipewire pulse isn't running properly

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire

When I first log on to my computer, no audio output device is detected. When I run `pipewire-pulse` in the terminal it gives this output

```
[W][00099.552106] mod.rt       | [     module-rt.c:  297 translate_error()] RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs
[W][00099.552312] mod.rt       | [     module-rt.c:  622 set_nice()] could not set nice-level to -11: Input/output error
[W][00099.555247] mod.protocol-pulse | [        server.c:  612 start_unix_server()] server 0x557ecf5b0d70: unlinking stale socket '/run/user/1000/pulse/native'
536870912
```

and it starts to detect the hdmi output. But when I go to close the terminal, it stops detecting the hdmi.

when I run `systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-session-manager` it outputs this

```
    ● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-03-07 18:18:04 CST; 28min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 2446 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 38364)
     Memory: 6.7M
        CPU: 11.317s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─2446 /usr/local/bin/pipewire
Mar 07 18:18:04 benboybb-Inspiron-3656 pipewire[2446]: [W][00018.341540] mod.rt       | [     module-rt.c:  278 pw_rtkit_check_xdg_portal()] Can't find xdg-portal: (null)
Mar 07 18:18:04 benboybb-Inspiron-3656 pipewire[2446]: [W][00018.341579] mod.rt       | [     module-rt.c:  991 pipewire__module_init()] found session bus but no portal
Mar 07 18:18:04 benboybb-Inspiron-3656 systemd[2438]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-03-07 18:18:04 CST; 28min ago
   Main PID: 2449 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 38364)
     Memory: 6.4M
        CPU: 446ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
```

I've tried googling all the warnings individually and I can't find anyone who is have my exact problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS if that helps